# How to know real IP address or not?

Tags: perl, ip

I have some log file with IP addresses. 
Does anybody know how can I define whether IP address real or private?
I'm using perl script.

Comment: what does real or private mean to you?

Comment: real ip addresses are seen in the internet, private - not.

Answer (score 2):

It is defined in [RFC 1819](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html):

> private internets:
>
> ```
>  10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>  172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>  192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
> ```

Comment: Maybe you could also note "special" IP addresses. Chapter 3 of [RFC 3330](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt) has a summary table.

Comment: And in a similar sense on IPv6 in [RFC 5156](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5156).